# JSON file returning associative array with extra fields

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to pass data from back end into the front end with JSON file, but instead of returning an associative any time stamp as key and values, it returns extra field from the table.

Anyone who can help me to hide extra fields?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChartController extends Controller
{
    public  function speedHistory($notification_id){

        $o_notification = Notification::find(intval($notification_id));
        $o_status = Status::where('name','speed')->first();

        $o_response = $o_notification->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

        if($o_response){
            return response()->json($o_response->toArray());
        }else{
            // return an empty json array instead of false
            //return false;
            return response()->json(array());
        }
    }
}
```

The return looks like this, I was expecting to get the value which is 72 in this case and the time stamp.

```
[{"value":"72","pivot":{"notification_id":1,"status_id":2,"values":"72","created_at":"2017-01-10 12:48:29","updated_at":"2017-01-10 12:48:29"}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the result you want:

```
$o_response = $o_notification->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($item, $key) {
        return collect([
            'values' => $item->pivot->values,
            'created_at' => $item->pivot->created_at
        ]);
    });
```

Then just return

```
return response()->json($o_response);
```

Comment: shall I ask you, why it is returning to me an associative array, instead of collections. This is what I get. Only one active area.[{"value":"72","created_at":"2017-01-10 12:48:29"}]

Comment: It should return a collection of collections (I've converted the array to collection (see `collect([values])`) so that you have the handy helpers of collection available to you. The result you posted is just an array of all the values that were found. If you were to insert more statuses with $o_status->id to the notification, you should get more results in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The relation will return a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections), so you can use the [only function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-only) to only get the keys you need.

Like so:

```
$o_response = $o_notification->statuses()
    ->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
    ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->only(['value', 'created_at']);
```

**Update:**

The answer above will not work if there are multiple results in the set. In this case, you can use [the map function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map).

```
$o_response = $o_notification->statuses()
    ->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
    ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($v) {
        return [
            'value' => $v->value,
            'created_at' => $v->created_at
        ];
    });
```

Comment: He has "value" and "created_at" in pivot column so this won't work as is.

Comment: instead it returns an empty array.

Comment: I have updated my answer, try the solution with the mapping function.